Load Data using Flink Job from Database with Scheduler
Customer is not interested in using CDC/kafka approach to load data from database, instead asking to use scheduler approach.
There is a fromCollection api to create DataStream, which accepts to load data from collection of records. This work well for one time read/load, but not for schedule scenario.
Any suggestions/references/best approach to follow?
Thanks In Adv
Venkata
Any suggestions/references/best approach to follow?

If I understand correctly, you want to have a source that periodically loads data from a database?  If so then you could use a RichSourceFunction, and do the data fetching periodically inside the run method and collect the data

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
